# Adobe AEM | Multiple image upload for image component (touch UI)

Tags: file-upload, aem

I'm trying to modify the existing image component so the edit dialog will have two tabs, the first tab is to upload the desktop version of the image and the second tab is to upload the mobile version of the image.

Initially the fileupload function worked, when there's only one field for the image. The image will be created as a file under the content folder.

I modified the component and have the field with different name. The images are created in the content folder, but it is not rendered in the UI.

If we use "file" as the properties name, it will work, but when we upload the second image it will be overwritten. Seems like it only recognizes "file" as name.

Do you happen to know how to render the images that have been created in the content folder or to configure the file name to be rendered ?

```
<content
    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
    sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/container">
<layout
        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
        sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/layouts/tabs"
        type="nav"/>
<items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
    <desktop
            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
            jcr:title="Desktop"
            sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/section">
        <layout
                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/layouts/fixedcolumns"/>
        <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
            <column
                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                    sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/container">
                <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                    <imagePathDesktop1
                            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                            sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/fileupload"
                            autoStart="{Boolean}false"
                            class="cq-droptarget"
                            fieldLabel="Desktop"
                            fileNameParameter="./imagePathDesktop"
                            mimeTypes="[image]"
                            multiple="{Boolean}true"
                            name="./imgDesktop"
                            title="Image Path"
                            uploadUrl="${suffix.path}"
                            useHTML5="{Boolean}true"/>
                </items>
            </column>
        </items>
    </desktop>
    <mobile
            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
            jcr:title="Mobile"
            sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/section">
        <layout
                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/layouts/fixedcolumns"/>
        <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
            <column
                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                    sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/container">
                <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                    <imagePathMobile2
                            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                            sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/fileupload"
                            autoStart="{Boolean}false"
                            class="cq-droptarget"
                            fieldLabel="Mobile"
                            fileNameParameter="./imagePathMobile"
                            fileReferenceParameter="./imageReferenceMob"
                            mimeTypes="[image]"
                            multiple="{Boolean}false"
                            name="./imgMobile"
                            title="Image Path"
                            uploadUrl="${suffix.path}"
                            useHTML5="{Boolean}true"/>
                </items>
            </column>
        </items>
    </mobile>
</items> </content>
```

Comment: Please share the dialog configuration so that it would be easy for others to debug the issue.

Comment: i have updated with dialog config.

Answer (score 1):

The Image class, and more specifically the `com.day.cq.commons.DownloadResource` class from which the Image inherits, expects the name of the resource under which a file is uploaded to be "file" unless explicitly overridden.  In compliance with this expectation, when a single component allows for multiple images, each image should be housed in a unique child resource and the files should be uploaded to a child resource of that resource named "file".  That said, your configuration is rather close to what would be needed.  I would suggest the following updates.

First, change the `name` parameters to be `./imgDesktop/file` and `./imgMobile/file` respectively.

Similarly update the `fileNameParameter` and `fileReferenceParameter` to include the relative path, for example, `./imgDesktop/fileReference`.

You will also need to add hidden dialog properties which will set the `sling:resourceType` of ./imgDesktop and ./imgMobile to something which extends from `foundation/components/parbase` as the image rendering mechanism is `libs/foundation/components/parbase/img.GET.java`.  The OOB textimage component located at `wcm/foundation/components/textimage` is a good example of this, it sets the `sling:resourceType` of the image resource to `foundation/components/image`.

The path to use to present your image would then be `resource.path + "/imgDesktop.img.png"` and `resource.path + "/imgMobile.img.png"` respectively.

Comment: I've change the name parameters to be ./imgDesktop/file and ./imgMobile/file . and update fileNameParameter and fileReferenceParameter to include the relative path .  The file is now created under the node immobile and imgDesktop. But when I try accessing the image with these URLs resource.path + "/imgDesktop.img.png" and resource.path + "/imgMobile.img.png"  , the image can't be rendered. It is rendered when the image file is stored under content_image folder.

Comment: Edited my prior answer to include some additional properties which need to be set to ensure your image resources have the right resourceType.

Comment: I'm kind of new to this AEM thing and i'm using JS to deal with the images, how would i get both images ?